# How to output s3SummaryObject to a csv file with each row on its own line-boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, boto3

I am trying to write the output of my s3objkeys to a csv file.

When I print my output, it looks like this:

```
my/file/path/to2017/.txt,
my/file/path/to2017/.txt,
my/file/path/to2018/.txt,
my/file/path/to2019/.txt,
```

When I write it to a csv file, it outputs it one a single line:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#Import boto3 module
import boto3
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import csv


#This is to List existing Buckets for the AWS account


#Set key variables

PREFIX = 'shredded/archive/'

bucket='my_bucket'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
    )

bucket1=s3.Bucket(bucket)

for obj in bucket1.objects.page_size(100):
      if '2017' in obj.key:
        d= str('{}, '.format(obj.key))
        print(d)
        #print('{0}, '.format( obj.key)
        with open('/my/path/2017_V3_files.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
             writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
             writer.writerows(d)
```

I want the obj.key output to be split up by line so when written to csv file, each row is on its own line. Any ideas or sugestions? Seems like a minor fix, but i am having issues solving this.

Comment: enclose `d` in a bracket so it becomes `writer.writerows([d])`, because `writerows` expects an iterable and you provide a string it writes each character to a new line, also you're opening the file every loop it matches, you should open it before the loop

Comment: also if you are writing a single row you should use `writerow` as opposed to `writerows`